# Migrate Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle10g, oracle12c

I had to connect my Oracle 10g XE (10.2.0.1) with Visual Studio 2012.

Since I found that 10g is not compatible now, so I want to migrate it to higher version - 12c.

I have successfully installed Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition, but it's upgrade assistant says that you have to upgrade your 10g (10.2.0.1) to the version 10.2.0.5, then DB can be migrated to 12c.

**Question: How to upgrade Oracle 10.2.0.1 to 10.2.0.5 ?**

I couldn't find the patch links from internet, I have searched a lot on the internet but didn't not get an amazing solution that resolves my problem in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

This message is an error in the installer. It is applicable to other editions of Oracle (for example to a Standard Edition) but XE does not have such version as 10.2.0.5. Even with an Oracle support contract paid, there is simply no such version on metalink. You need to export-import like described [in this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18131/oracle-10g-xe-to-11g-xe-upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

You need a metalink account to download this patch (legally); it's probably easier to export the database and import it into a fresh 12c instance.